# Java recursive method difference

Tags: java, recursion

What is the difference between the following two methods:

```
public boolean recursionMethodOne(Node n) {
   System.out.println(n.getValue());
   return recursionMethodOne(n.next());
}

public void recursionMethodTwo(Node n) {
   System.out.println(n.getValue());
   recursionMethodTwo(n.next());
}
```

Which one do you use for recursion and what is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: None of them ends.

Comment: Are we getting live questions from a test? Sorry, but the difference is quite obvious: Both will (very likely) not work.

Comment: Well the main thing I want to know is when do you `return` in a recursive method and when do you just call the method's name without returning?

Comment: @FelipeSulser or they end rather fast with a NullPointerException.

Comment: If your method is supposed to return information, then it should return information. If not, then not.

Comment: @Kingamere: It depends on your needs. You can you both, just choose the one best suited to your needs.

Comment: @Kingamere, all methods return as the last statement. If no return statme nt is included or you get to last statement in a method wihtout seeing a return, a `return NULL` is effectively called. (kinda... this isnt REALLY what happens but close enough). To end a recursion chain, you need some condition under which the recursive method will not call another function and the entire rucursion stack will return. Wrapping your second statements in `if( n.next() != null ) { } ` would work so that the stack returns after printing all of the values.

Comment: @gbtimmon you are wrong. Every function with a returning type different from void needs explicitly a "return something;". A function with a returning type void can finish without an explicit "return;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your codes doesn't exits. You need to add a return for a test condition. For example:

```
public void recursionMethodTwo(Node n) {
   if (n == null) {
       // Standard way to exit a void function without executing remaing code
       // note that return null; doesn't compile
       return;  
   }
   System.out.println(n.getValue());
   recursionMethodTwo(n.next());
}
```

Returning a value or not depends on the kind of function.
For example if you need to calculate a factorial you need a result, if you need to print a list you don't.

So for your example seems that the method two is most closer to your needs.

Otherwise you need to ask yourself what is the returning boolean value of the function? If you have a nice answer to this question you can implement the code returning a value.

Comment: How can you `return` in a void method?

Comment: @Kingamere using `return;`. Note there is no expression between `return` and `;`.

Comment: @kingamere `return;` is the standard way to exit immediately from a function returning `void`.

Comment: The return statement actually does something that you probably werent aware of. Its main function is to change the "program counter". This is a value that tell the computer what line of code to run next. When a return is run it sets the program counter to return to running the function that call the current function from where it left off. The concept of a "Return value" is just an extra there to be convenient, a language doesn't need return values to work. There is no rule saying you have to pass anything back. `return;` is the same as `return null;` more or less.

Comment: @gbtimmon return null returns the value null. It can be used for any function returning an object. return; exit from current void function without returning a value. This two concepts are very different!

Comment: We are talking about the java language, not the byte code. What exactly is returned in the byte code is out of scope now. Putting return null; instead of return; creates a not compilable code and viceversa.

Comment: @David Lorenze MARINO Im keeping it simple for someone new ... its closer to return garbage value in return register then rely on the compiler to prevent the program from reading the register since the signature is void -- but thats not useful right now is it ? –